# Ajax login: parseerror

Tags: ajax, parse-error

I'm making Ajax login and I've got parse error. Code sends username to login2.php and then code have to receive password. There's Jquery and ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#submit').click(function() {
var username = $('#username').val();
var password = $('#password').val();
if (username.length == 0) {
$('#login_er').html("Klaida");
} else if (password.length == 0) {
$('#login_er').html("Klaida2");
} else {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',  
    data: username,
    url: 'login2.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        var password2 = data[0]
$('#login_er').html("success" + password2);
},//success
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
});//ajax
}
});
});
```

and login2.php

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include ("nustatymai.php");
    if (!logged_in) {
    $username = json_decode($_POST['username']);
    $sql= "SELECT pass FROM `users` WHERE username =:username";
    $login = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $login->bindParam(':username', $username);
    if($login->execute()){
    $login2 = $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    json_encode($login2);
    }
    };
```

what's wrong?

Comment: First of all, structure your code a bit please. And add come brackets on your ajax code up there as well so we can see better.

Comment: I just added full ajax.